# ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] App Engine Flex failed to configure resources

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to deploy an app with

```
gcloud beta app deploy
```

I am confronted with

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] App Engine Flex failed to configure resources.

Has anyone seen this error?

Comment: We faced same issue. No changes to config was made recently. Details here: https://serverfault.com/questions/898586/app-engine-flex-failed-to-configure-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the same error, my problem was that i left out the part:

```
network:
  name: your-network-name
```

Maybe you've got another issue, but i'd recommend to trace back changes in your app.yaml.

Also you could inspect the used app.yaml via the Google Console -> App Engine -> Versions -> last column `config: view`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This may have been correlated with a recent release related to the "enable_health_checks:false" parameter for applications where split_health_checks are enabled.

Could you try to deploy with "enable_health_checks:true" or "split_health_checks=false" [1] ?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried to deploy with this, for no avail!

Answer (score 0):

Gonna need a little more information:

1. What version of the SDK are you running? "Beta" on one version is different from "beta" on another...want to make sure we're talking about the same tools.
2. Have you ever been able to deploy this app before? With or without beta?
3. What's your app.yaml file look like? Please copy/paste the code into your question (removing sensitive information, obviously).

If you add this info to your question, we should be able to get further troubleshooting.

Comment: I have the same issue on current app engine. Details posted here: https://serverfault.com/questions/898586/app-engine-flex-failed-to-configure-resources